# Range Selection in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, with-statement

I am trying to define a range for the active sheet and select it within a for loop in vba and for some reason whenever I do that it gives me an object/application defined error message.  Here is what I am trying to run:

```
With ActiveSheet
Set rng2 = .Range("C" & position)
.Range(rng2).Select
End With
```

I am rather new to vba and am very confused why this won't work.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've declared and set `rng2` as a Range object there is no need to wrap it with `Range`.

```
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & position)
rng2.Select
```